# How to turn on device GPS in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

By using simple_permissions and location package of Dart, it is only asking for user permission to ALLOW or DENY the app to use device location to show the current location of user on Google Maps.
When i turn on the GPS manually on my device, I'm able to get the current location, but how can I ask the user to enable GPS from the app itself with a dialog to enable the GPS like Google Maps?

Comment: I don't think so you have to create such dialog for this. however, if you want to create such a function, then you have to create your own plugin. and call it to through method channel.

Comment: So is there any way to open the location settings page for Android and IOS as well?

Comment: maybe this link could help you
 https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/settings#-example-tab-

Comment: @satish when using the above plugin to open the settings page, it is throwing MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method wifi on channel plugins.ly.com/settings)  error

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation) it worked for me

Comment: @josue.0 yes this one is working fine thank you

Answer (score -4, accepted):

By using [access_settings_menu](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/access_settings_menu), the location settings page can be opened for Android devices

Answer (score 7):

This [Plugin](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation) shows the Turn on Gps Dialogue for flutter (as like the Native android)

Comment: Did you mean this kind of dialog shown in my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58994925/5209982 ?

Comment: exactly the native dialogue feature is added in the plugin recently and im using it more than a month

Answer (score 3):

If you already have geolocator or if you are using the two (geolocator and location packages), then first import one of them as an alias, for example for location, import it as:

```
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;

loc.Location location = loc.Location();//explicit reference to the Location class
Future _checkGps() async {
if (!await location.serviceEnabled()) {
  location.requestService();
 }
}
```

Notice that use of var location = Location() or var location = loc.Location() wont work, you have to reference the Location class exclusively with the alias loc for the example above.

Then call the method in the initState as below to be checked every once the app starts as below:

```
@Override
void initState()
{
 super.initState();//comes first for initState();
 _checkGPS();
}
```

Comment: Hi , I doing same process but i am getting this error https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/821

Answer (score 2):

you can user location library

```
var location = Location();

  Future checkGps() async {
    if (!await location.serviceEnabled()) {
      location.requestService();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of (android_intent: ^2.0.2), you can request GPS in android

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  Get.dialog(
    AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Can't get current location"),
      content: const Text('Please make sure you enable GPS and try again'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {
              GeneralController.to.isPermissionAsked.value = true;
              final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS');
              intent.launch();
              Get.back();
            })
      ],
    ),
    barrierDismissible: false,
  );
}
```

and handle it in

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
switch (state) {
  case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
    print("app in resumed");      
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    print("app in inactive");
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.paused:
    print("app in paused");
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    print("app in detached");
    break;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

if you using the Geolocator package , just use this code below and Geolocator will open a location service for the user to turn it on then rebuild your widget

```
await Geolocator.openLocationSettings().then(value){

   //call function of whatever you need to do  
}
```