# Native Dialog for location setting on Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to implement a Dialog for Location setting like the image below which gets triggered when app requires GPS location and doesn't find. Hitting **OK** will right away turn on the system GPS. This seems more convenient for users instead of taking them to location and manually turn on.
Is it possible to implement such thing in Flutter?

[image]

Expanded View of dialog:

[image]

Comment: Have you already looked ad https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler ?

Comment: Not sure how that's gonna help me. I already have location permissions. This is the case when the app looks for GPS location but finds GPS is off so it requests user to turn on GPS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Credits to Rajesh, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58704384/5209982). The [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location) lets you add this native dialog for a quick location setting.

The implementation is quite simple as this:

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';

var location = Location();

Future _checkGps() async {
if(!await location.serviceEnabled()){
   location.requestService();
  }
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _checkGps();
}
```

Comment: Is this also works for IOS ?

Comment: using this function it is showing a default dialog one option 'Cancel'; can we modify this dialog and maybe add 'Settings' button to take the user to Location Settings page?

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, try this code:

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val requestLocation = 199

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableLoc()
    }
    private fun enableLoc() {
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        mLocationRequest.interval = 10000
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 5000
      //  mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)

        val client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
        val task =
            client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        task.addOnSuccessListener(this) {
            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
            // location requests here.
            // ...
        }

        task.addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
            if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    e.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        requestLocation
                    )
                } catch (sendEx: SendIntentException) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```